# click favourite star

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to let the star colored when I click on it , but because I have both of Javascript and HTML file in separate folder , how can I revert the function in javascript to the html file?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/7YjPu/47/)

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />   
<ul>
<li  id="fav">★</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
function addRating(obj) {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('#rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}

$("#fav").click(function(){
    addRating(obj);
});
```

Css

```
li{float:left; margin-left:9px;display: inline-block;color: #F0F0F0;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #666666;font-size:30px;}
.highlight, .selected {color:#F4B30A;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #F48F0A;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `this` to the `addRating` it holds the context of the owner object.

```js
function addRating(obj) {
  $('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('#rating').val((index + 1));
    if (index == $("li").index(obj)) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

$("#fav").on('click',function() {
  addRating(this);
});
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.highlight,
.selected {
  color: #F4B30A;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #F48F0A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />

<ul>
  <li id="fav">★</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You should really explain what changes you made and how this answers the question.

Comment: @RonyLoud why it's work when the css is like " li {....}"  but not works if the css is like " li#fav {...}" because i have more than li in my code?

Comment: @rozab when you use " li#fav {...}" its by `id` which wins overs " li {....}"  as it is only element selector. So use `!important` to prioritize new class. Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/35a3aeuj/#&togetherjs=RNEUNIAfKp).

Comment: @RonyLoud , am just curious if it can be two method addfavourite();  and deletefavourite(); ,is that possible ?

Comment: Please post your `function` So that we come to know what you wanna achieve

Comment: I have an items page so when the user click on the favorite star it will add this item in his favorite list table in database, but how can I do it if he remove the star to delete the record from the database table https://jsfiddle.net/35a3aeuj/2/

Comment: Just place a attribute binded with the `id` of item in `li` and on removal of `selected` class invoke `ajax` to get that `id` removed from database

Comment: @can u show me how to do that please? , I try another soloution , but it doesn't work!

Comment: I don't know the exact db but as per my understanding may it helps [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/fy3sk1r9/#&togetherjs=1E8m6EONfQ)